# autohotkey: Cancel RButton user input after LButton pressed

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

In an fps I am trying to setup a hotkey such that when I am holding Lbutton (leftmouse), primary fire of a gun, and then tap RButton the LButton ceases and RButton commences. Ingame with no script, for other weapons, I get the desired result automatically. That is: I'm holding LButton, but if I also hold RButton 'after', the LButton ceases and the RButton's burst fire does its thing. However a different scoped weapon, with no script, freezes up when the above is done.

So I'm looking to, as soon as RButton is pressed, cease all user input of LButton until RButton's hotkey finishes.

```
~RButton
    ;Blockinput Mouse ;Send/Sendmouse
        Send, {Click Left}{Click Right}{Click Left}
    ;BlockInput off
        return
```

You can think of the Rbutton script as for a scoped rifle. Click Left activates scope, Click right fires it. Currently the desired behaviour only works when I completely remove my hand from LButton and then press RButton....I am also able to get ~LButton & ~RButton:: to work but that only covers the case when they r both first pressed at the exact same time, I want to cover the instance where LButton is pressed and held before RButton.

Ive tried applying blockinput, like seen above, had the UAC workaround to get it working, blocks certain things but doesnt seem to block any heldkeys when it is proc'd like the lbutton unless I'm missing something. If there was a "Freeze user input of LButton as soon as RButton procs, until RButton's script finishes" that would solve the problem I would think. I tried adding sleep delays, but they dont seem to help. The issue seems to be that LButton, when held, continues to proc when RButton first activates.

I used the below while holding LButton, and the sound DOES proc, so this must be possible to script.

```
*RButton::
Soundbeep
return
```

EDIT:

;code here works but only with that 100 sleep where i have to remove my hand from pressing the lbutton within 100ms of pressing rbutton.

```
*RButton::

GetKeyState, state, lbutton, p
if (state = "D")
{
soundbeep
send {Click Left Up}
sleep 100
;i need to actually disable the previous keypresses from it
}
    
    Send, {Click Right}{Click Left}{Click Right}
return
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your question, you don't really need to block user mouse input so much as Sending a Left MouseUp command if the Left mouse button was held down. I was having difficulty understanding what the end goal you were looking for was, but I wrote this based on what I was able to understand:

```
#SingleInstance Force

*RButton::
Soundbeep
If (getKeyState( "lbutton", "p" )){
   Click, Left, Up
   Send, {Click Left}{Click Right}{Click Left}
} else {
   Send, {Click Left}{Click Right}{Click Left}
}
return


esc::ExitApp
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on the clarification from the comments of the question, this should work. Understood functionality: If the right mouse button is clicked while the left mouse button is held down, release the LMB, but do not suppress the RMB input.

```
*~RButton::
If (getKeyState( "lbutton", "p" ))
   Click, Left, Up
return
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**
Now releasing the LMB before the RMB is pressed. I have a feeling that whatever game that you are playing will not be able to detect zero-tick switches between keystates, so I included a Sleep function that you can fine-tune/ remove as needed.

```
*RButton::
If (getKeyState( "lbutton", "p" )){
   Click, Left, Up
    Sleep 100
}
Click, Right, Down
KeyWait RButton
Click, Right, Up
return
```

Comment: This doesn't do it. The problem is LButton has to be released 'soon after' the rbutton is clicked. So the code I post above WORKs, but only with the minimum 100 sleep delay, and I have to remove my hand physically from pressing lbutton down. What I need is any of my own physical lbutton clicks disabled while rbutton's hotkey is running. If that doesn't make sense: just know I do need a way to physically stop any input from lbutton that I might get via physically clicking my mouse while rbutton's hotkey is running. holding lbutton shoudlnt affect rbuttons hotkey

Comment: Could you please either disclose how exactly I could replicate your issue, or what specific order of events you want to occur? At the present, the only way I can really test if any code I am writing works is if I send it to you and see if it does what you want it to. If you could disclose this info, I could possibly better understand and solve this issue.

Comment: IN a game You press and hold {Click Left}. Then you press and hold {Click Right}. {Click Right} is not cancelling out {Click Left}, infact {Click RIght} isn't even registering and only {Click Left} is registering. I need {Click Right} to be the only thing registering in this situation. A keyboard in a text editor: say u hold q then u hold w a second later at same time...what hapens? qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqwwwwwwwwwwwwwww. the w overwrites any input from q. I want this behaviour with from mouse.

Comment: The example with holding down the q and w really helped clarify the question, I updated the post @kite. If it works, please mark it as the accepted answer. If it doesn't, please lmk and tell me what I can improve.

Comment: right mouse scopes the gun, left mouse fires the gun. left mouse held then right mouse also held, causes a third behaviour where the gun ceases firing (we want the gun to cease firing AND scope). Unfortunately the updated script as written did not change the default behaviour.

Comment: Oh, so you need the LMB to be lifted before the right button is pressed? @kite

Comment: Potentially. If you just send LMB up at the start of RMB, it doesn't work unless it addresses the fact u are still holding LMB down. It's important it works for the case where LMB is actively held down. A Simple LMB & RMB:: only applies to both held initially at the same time, so don't do any of that.

Comment: Standard mouse cycles consist of a `MouseDown` and a `MouseUp` event, so unless the game that you are playing is constantly checking for the physical state of the mouse button (which is unlikely but not impossible), Releasing the LMB with a `MouseUp` event before holding the RMB down should do the trick. Then again, if it doesn't, just let me know. **ANSWER UPDATED** @kite

Comment: was able to get it to work up to 80% of the time fiddling with the sleep. 20% of the time its still behaving like the default behaviour as described prior tho (no scope no firing). is there anything else i can do to improve efficacy? ive tried including SetKeyDelay, 2000, 2000 at top of script; which i would have thought would make the system wait up to 2-4 seconds per send action before skipping it. but that doesnt seem to do anything

Comment: is there way to allocate more ram/cpu/resources to ahk so it runs smoother?

Comment: Im sure that there definitely is @kite, but that's a topic for another question

Comment: Also, regarding the inconsistent behaviour, I thought that I mentioned that increasing the duration of the `Sleep` command in line four up from `100`  to something higher would increase the reliability of the script

Comment: "was able to get it to work up to 80% of the time fiddling with the sleep." it was fiddled with quite rigorously

Comment: Oh, welp, sorry about that. I found this if it may be of any help to you https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=6413. I would normally reconfigure the script myself and test it for you, but as I don't really know what game you are using it on, this is the best that I can safely do